# python pandas time elapsed between dynamic range

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, pandas

I am a new python/pandas user. I am trying to get a time delta (in secs) between dynamic ranges (based on diff in values) of a time series data frame. My sample dataframe is:

```
time                          price
2013-04-26 09:30:03-04:00       101
2013-04-26 09:30:04-04:00       101
2013-04-26 09:30:05-04:00       102
2013-04-26 09:30:06-04:00       105
2013-04-26 09:30:07-04:00       104
2013-04-26 09:30:08-04:00       105
2013-04-26 09:30:09-04:00       106
2013-04-26 09:30:10-04:00       104
2013-04-26 09:30:11-04:00       110
2013-04-26 09:30:12-04:00       109
2013-04-26 09:30:13-04:00       111
2013-04-26 09:30:14-04:00       108
2013-04-26 09:30:15-04:00       106
2013-04-26 09:30:16-04:00       107
2013-04-26 09:30:17-04:00       107
2013-04-26 09:30:18-04:00       108
2013-04-26 09:30:19-04:00       109
2013-04-26 09:30:20-04:00       109
2013-04-26 09:30:21-04:00       110
```

I am trying to get the time delta between price diff of 4. Once the diff in price is reached, that price point become the 'starting point' for the next calculation and so on.
The desired result is something like (time delta in secs):

```
time                       price    time delta
2013-04-26 09:30:03-04:00   101 
2013-04-26 09:30:04-04:00   101 
2013-04-26 09:30:05-04:00   102 
2013-04-26 09:30:06-04:00   105      3
2013-04-26 09:30:07-04:00   104 
2013-04-26 09:30:08-04:00   105 
2013-04-26 09:30:09-04:00   106 
2013-04-26 09:30:10-04:00   104 
2013-04-26 09:30:11-04:00   110      5
2013-04-26 09:30:12-04:00   109 
2013-04-26 09:30:13-04:00   111 
2013-04-26 09:30:14-04:00   108 
2013-04-26 09:30:15-04:00   106      4
2013-04-26 09:30:16-04:00   107 
2013-04-26 09:30:17-04:00   107 
2013-04-26 09:30:18-04:00   108 
2013-04-26 09:30:19-04:00   109 
2013-04-26 09:30:20-04:00   109 
2013-04-26 09:30:21-04:00   110      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how great this is performance wise.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gen = df.price.iteritems()

def get_deltas(gen):
    time, value = next(gen)
    deltas = [np.nan]  # initial value
    for line in gen:
        if np.abs(line[1] - value) >= 4:
            deltas.append(np.abs(line[0] - time))
            time, value = line
        else:
            deltas.append(np.nan)    
    return deltas

deltas = get_deltas(df.price.iteritems())
df['deltas'] = deltas

In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
                     price   deltas
time                               
2013-04-26 13:30:03    101      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:04    101      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:05    102      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:06    105  0:00:03
2013-04-26 13:30:07    104      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:08    105      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:09    106      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:10    104      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:11    110  0:00:05
2013-04-26 13:30:12    109      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:13    111      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:14    108      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:15    106  0:00:04
2013-04-26 13:30:16    107      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:17    107      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:18    108      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:19    109      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:20    109      NaN
2013-04-26 13:30:21    110  0:00:06
```